# Ingress controller cannot forward requests to grpc backend : "service does not have any active endpoint"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, nginx-ingress

An nginx ingress controller is meant to be deployed in its own namespace. The ingresses that use it have to be deployed in their own namespace, then use the "nginx" ingress class to target the nginx ingress controller.

Then, the ingress controller uses the kubernetes API to retrieve services that lead to the target pods. The ingress controller "knows" which namespace to target, basing itself on the namespace the ingress has been declared in.

Now, this last part does not work in my case. Here is what i find in the ingress controller logs :

```
Service "development/users-api" does not have any active Endpoint.
```

Obviously i already checked if the services were working from one backend pod to the other. I also managed to make it work using the cross-namespace service notation, using this kind of command from the ingress controller :

```
curl  users-api.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

But it seems the ingress controller is not capable of contacting the service basing itself on the natural name outside of the namespace - as it would be the expected behaviour.

Here is my ingress spec (using terraform)

```
resource kubernetes_ingress_v1 "api-ingress" {
    metadata {
        name = "drop-apis-ingress"
        namespace = terraform.workspace
        annotations = {
            "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect" = true
            "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol" = "GRPC"
            "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex" = true
            "cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer" = "letsencrypt-${terraform.workspace}"
            "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet": "grpc_read_timeout 3600s; grpc_send_timeout 3600s;"
        }
    }

    spec {
        tls {
            hosts = ["${terraform.workspace}.backend.domain.io"]
            secret_name = "letsencrypt-tls-${terraform.workspace}"
        }

        ingress_class_name = "nginx"

        rule {
            host = "${terraform.workspace}.backend.domain.io"  
            http {
                dynamic path {
                    for_each = local.apis
                    content {
// grpc service prefix 
                        path = "/app.protobuf.shared.${title(path.key)}"
                        path_type = "Prefix"
                        backend {
                            service {
                                name = "${path.key}-api"
                                port {
                                    number = 8080
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My service spec is templated in a Helm chart and simply works (tried connection with curl)

Do you see anything that i am missing ?

Comment: What version of the NGINX ingress controller are you using?  I see there's been on/off issues with what you've described.  [GitHub issue 6135](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6135)

Comment: the nginx image version is v1.6.4 : `registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.6.4@sha256:15be4666c53052484dd2992efacf2f50ea77a78ae8aa21ccd91af6baaa7ea22f`

Comment: I don't suppose you can share your deployment manifests and ingress rules?  (redact any identifying/sensitive info of course).  Also, is this the only service that's giving you this error?  Do you have other services that are working fine?

Comment: I just added the ingress spec. All the services are giving the same error (i got 8)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : check that your service paths are correct.

The problem was I had recently changed the package name for my GRPC services.

`app.protobuf.public` had recently became `app.protobuf.shared`. I thought i had deployed the new version of the services, with the new `shared` path, but it was not the case.

As a result the following ingress rule did not match anything :

```
path = "/app.protobuf.shared.${title(path.key)}"
```

NOW the error messages didn't make any f_ing sense to be honest. I didn't even think of checking the service versions because everything seemed like there was an issue on the Kubernetes services and their interaction with the ingress controller.

Actually in this message :
"service does not have any active endpoint" - it's possible that the "service" term refers to the gRPC service. But it would still be very confusing.

Also that doesn't explain the weird behavior of the ingress controller still being able to dial the gRPC server through the `.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` hostname.